# LAG and LEAD based on parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, lag, lead

I have table - Invoices, with such structure:

| Id | InvoiceNo | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 11-12-21 |
| 2 | 20 | 12-12-21 |
| 3 | 30 | 13-12-21 |
| 4 | 40 | NULL |
| 5 | 50 | 14-12-21 |
| 6 | 60 | NULL |
| 7 | 70 | NULL |
| 8 | 80 | 15-12-21 |

What I need to do - I need to find InvoiceNo's, the date field of the next or previous line of which contains null.
So, based on provided data - I should receive:

| InvoiceNo |
| --- |
| 30 |
| 50 |
| 80 |

But how to do this? One option that I found - `LAG()` and `LEAD()` functions, and with these functions I can receive numbers and dates, but cannot use parameters - so cannot provide "Date is not null" check.

Comment: an you explain the logic behind this output?

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Mureinik if previous or next record of current row contains null in "Date" field - I should return this row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag` and `lead` to find the previous and next rows, and then wrap the query with another query that returns only the rows where one of them was `null`. Note that `lag` of the first row and `lead` of the last raw will return `null` by default, so you need to explicitly state a non-`null` default, such as `getdate()`:

```sql
SELECT InvoiceNo
FROM   (SELECT InvoiceNo,
               LAG(Date, 1, GETDATE()) OVER (ORDER BY InvoiceNo) AS lag_date,
               LEAD(Date, 1, GETDATE()) OVER (ORDER BY InvoiceNo) AS lead_date
        FROM   invoices) t
WHERE   lag_date IS NULL OR lead_date IS NULL
```

Comment: Good answer, thank you! But what if I have a situation - two Date = null in a row? Current solution shows them too, and conditions don't work:( I tried to add "date is not null" to inner query, and outer too

Comment: Updated the description

Comment: Omg, I forgot about brackets - works fine, thank  you!